# Construct an 32 X 8 RAM using 4 of 16 X4 RAM chips

Tags: digital-logic, design, memory

*Note1*: I know that the 16 X 4 memory contains 4 output lines. there is also a 4-bit input to construct the 16 WORDS.

*Note2*: The problem arises as the RAM 32 X 8 contains 8 output lines and 5-bit input. But i want to use *4* of RAM 16 X 4.

**Question**: What can i do about my design to get the RAM 32 X 8 with correct input and output lines.

Comment: Other than multiplexing them?

Comment: I want to know all possible implementations, makes no difference.

Comment: Use the most signifigant address to select one of the two pairs of 16 x 4 RAMs.

Comment: No, you don't want to know all possible implementations. Some are crazy-minded, but would still work. For example, you could construct an internal 6-bit address bus, arranged as a 64x4 memory and use the 5-bit incoming address bus as the upper 5 bits, with two cycles required per byte output used to step the lowest address bit from 0 to 1, latching first one group of 4 bits, then the other group, to make up the byte. Given your willingness to waste the time of others by asking for all methods, I'd be tempted to toss out that one instead of the much more obvious one detailed by @PeterBennett .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You double the number of addresses by using the high order address bit to generate a chip select (If you also have a chip select line then use logic gates to combine it with the address line).
You double the number of bits by putting two chips in parallel. Same address and control lines to both of them but different data lines.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHwbIp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>